# Make the Firestore emulator slow on purpose

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, emulation

I'm working with Firestore from Google Firebase, which is way faster with the emulator on my local development machine than in the cloud. (not complaining, just stating a fact)

Is there a way to make the emulator respond slower on purpose so I can better simulate a end user's experience?

**Edit:**
I am using Firestore behind layers of abstraction in a complex application. This requires a more sophisticated solution than putting something like this in front of every Firestore call:

```
await new Promise<void>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500));
```

Comment: I suggest that you look into [`setTimeout() method`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) JavaScript timing events.

Comment: @RJC, I have; just don't know how to inject that into the Firestore emulator.

Comment: You can delay your Firestore calls with setTimeout wrapper. `setTimeout(() => someFirestoreFunction(data), 1000);`

Comment: @OceanOverflow, I know. However I am using Firestore behind layers of abstraction in a complex application. This requires a more sophisticated solution than putting timeout wrappers everywhere. (I'll update my question with this information.)

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order for the community to best assist you in your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the browser's developer tools' network throttling feature if you have a web app?

[image]